# i need to store the id in a selected row in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

```
$typ= category3::where('type_name', '=', $request->name)->where('category','=',$request->category)->get();
```

Above is the code in file to select the row from table category3.

Now what should i do to get the id of that selected row stored to a variable called $type_id?

Comment: i typed ,get the id stored to variable. which i can use to store some data in another table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pluck()` method to select one column. Example:

```
$typ = category3::where('type_name', '=', $request->name)
    ->where('category','=',$request->category)
    ->pluck('id');
```

It will return only the value of `id` from the row matched with your query, if more than one row matched with your query it will return the first row's result. You can use the `$typ` as `$type_id` or you can store the query result in `$type_id` instead of `$typ`.

Or you can pass all needed columns name in an array inside `get()` method as a parameter. Example:

```
$typ= category3::where('type_name', '=', $request->name)
    ->where('category','=',$request->category)
    ->get(['id','otherIfNeeded']); // if no parameter it will return all column's value
```

It will return a collection of data matched with the query. To retrieve the ids in `blade` file

```
@foreach($typ as $type_id)
    {{ $type_id->id }}
@endofreach
```

Answer (score 0):

to get id from those rows,it's simple just use foreach and access what property you want to use.

```
foreach($typ as $type){
echo $type->id;
}
```